# How to export e‑mail in the msg format with Thunderbird?

Tags: 64-bit, thunderbird

Simple question, but I couldn’t find the answer without installing non Thunderbird third party…
Converting online would also be an option…

By default Thunderbird can export e‑mail in the html or the eml format. But I’m required to upload one of my e‑mail to a website using Outlook’s msg format…

I don’t want to buy Outlook…

Comment: Thunderbird stores mail in mbox format - create a "new folder" and move your message there, then look in your profile directory and you should see a file containing a single message.  Or you could use one of the mbox to maildir utilities.

Comment: @ivanivan : I know, and then I can export it using the eml format… not the msg format used by Outlook. **You didn’t understood the question**.

Comment: Ah, outlook would be pst files and such.  Proprietary. You'd need to get the message into outlook, and since they want teh entire message I'm guessing you need it intact with all headers, etc.  Good luck!

Comment: @ivanivan : **No.** This [file format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912(v=exchg.80).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This sort-of works for Outlook 2016.

Once you have exported the email from Thunderbird in eml format,
run the following command (change office number to yours if not Outlook 2016) :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /eml "path/to/file.eml"
```

This option may have been neglected by Microsoft, but if the result is
acceptable (or can be tweaked), do `File / Save As` to save in msg format.

Comment: I didn’t bought Outlook. And I don’t want to do it on NetBSD.

Comment: Sorry … undone …

Comment: Even if this answer doesn't work for you, it can still help someone else who finds your post via google. As you don't have Outlook, you will have to get some 3rd-party product. However, the better ones are commercial.

Answer (score 0):

> This sort-of works for Outlook 2016 [...]

Not sure if answering just to thank someone is acceptable.

I'll go for it anyway. This approach **works like a charm** also in Outlook 365 (v.2010 Build 13328.20292 as of Nov. 2020).

Thank you for saving lots of ass here.

**Edit:** the command line trick doesn't even seem to be needed anymore. Outlook 365 v.2010 opens *.eml files directly (e.g. via right click in Windows Explorer), and then you can do a "Save As" and save it as *.msg.

Comment: It s from thunderbird to Outlook and not the way other.

Comment: Pardon? Yes it is, that's the point of it. EML to MSG conversion. I am aware that this is  only viable when you have Outlook, but this was already stated above.

Comment: Outlook isn t free for doing this.

Comment: harrymc wrote
> Even if this answer doesn't work for you, *it can still help someone else who finds your post via google*. 

Which it exactly did for me. Thanks for not downvoting.

Comment: My insurrance want `.msg` files for proving I book the tickets.

Comment: Unbelievable that they want this proprietary format that most people have no access to. They must be d*mb. 
Or they are intelligent and aware that you can tamper with EML files using any text editor, but not so with MSG files...
Anyway, you might want to use an online converter for EML -> MSG. 
I used aconvert.com/document/eml-to-msg with good success today.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116071/discussion-between-david-p-and-user2284570).